# A Driver Circuit for DC to AC Converter

Tags: mosfet-driver, gate-driving, dc-ac

I am simulating a DC to AC converter on LTSpice and I used if statements to make the circuit work. These if statements are located near the top of the image below, where the "lonely" voltage sources are. How do I implement these if statements on the breadboard? Someone told me to use a driver circuits and I looked for one on google. However, I am not sure how to construct/simulate a driver ciruit using basic circuit elements in LTSpice.
[image]enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you use PFETs for M5 and M7 you can avoid if statements. Source will connect to +12 volt and gate will drive from 12 volts to 0 volts to activate the PFET.

Comment: @Andyaka What do I do with the sources labelled out_1 to out_4? Do I keep them as is in the picture or do I remove them entirely? Will your method force me do manually do any switching to get the AC current or will LTSpice do this on its own?